# Can't display canvas element for react picture app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a simple app to take a picture using reactJS.

It seems that all of the examples I can find are old school using refs and all that fun stuff that we don't use anymore, which I am trying to avoid.

But regardless, currently it is not working. According to the tutorials I have seen, I need to pass in my video element into the canvas, which I do not understand.

Anyway my current component is as follows:

```
export default class Camera extends Component {
 constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.canvasRef = React.createRef()
    this.videoRef = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      stream: {}
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { width: 640, height: 480 } })

      if (stream) {
        this.setState({
          stream
        })
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }

  render () {
    const video = document.getElementById('video')
    const context = (this.canvasRef && this.canvasRef.getContext('2d'))
    context && context.drawImage(document.getElementById('video'), 0, 0, 640, 480)
    return (
      <>
        <video id='video' width='640' heigh='480' src={this.state.stream} autoPlay={true}/>
        <button onClick={(evt) => console.warn('take photo')}>Take photo!</button>
        <div>
          <canvas id='canvas' width='640' height='480' ref={ref => (this.canvasRef = ref)} />
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

As it stands all I am getting is a blank screen. The issue seems to be with the canvas, but I don't know what I did wrong.
I should also mention that ideally I don't even want to use refs. I would like to just use props and maybe the state, but I suppose first I have to get it to work as it is right now.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, imperative animations is still a very valid use case for refs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html.

In your constructor, declare your canvas:

```
this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
```

Then use it like so

```
const canvas = this.canvasRef.current;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

And in your render function, assign the ref to your canvas element:

```
<canvas ref={this.canvasRef} />
```

I personally found it pretty tricky to work Canvas into the react lifecycle but it definitely can be done. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately it still isn't working... canvas.current is currently `null`. Is there something else that needs to be done so that it isn't null at that point in the render function?

Comment: I should also note that with these changes I now get a `DOMException` in the try/catch block on the `componentWillMount`. If I do remove the try/catch block the error I get in the console is `Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.` Any idea what is up with that?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot to mention that you have to set the ref in your render function. 
`<canvas ref={this.canvasRef}/> `. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Not sure what exactly is causing the error without some more error logging. Try printing it with `console.error(err)` and see if that helps?

Comment: `DOMException` is all I get in `console.error`. I have updated the code to reflect your suggested changes. This is happening when I try to get the stream from `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

Comment: Update: please ignore my previous comments, this has to do with the access of the camera being denied. Not sure when that happened. But now I can move on. unfortunately the whole issue with not being able to do this.canvasRed.current.getContext still stands